# Completely monotonic function intersect

Tags: functions

Is there any proof that two "completely monotonic" functions ($f,g: (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) would intersect at most at one point?

Completely monotonic means: The $n$'th derivative of each function satisfies $(−1)^ n f^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$, $(−1)^ n g^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$, $x \in (0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect. Two completely monotonic functions can intersect at more than $1$ point, in fact they can intersect at infinitely many points.

Consider
$$\color{red}{f(x) = \left\lfloor \dfrac{2x}{\pi} \right\rfloor+\sin\left(x-\left\lfloor \dfrac{2x}{\pi} \right\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}2\right) - 0.125}$$
and
$$\color{blue}{g(x) = 1.125+ \left\lfloor \dfrac{2x}{\pi} \right\rfloor-\cos\left(x-\left\lfloor \dfrac{2x}{\pi} \right\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}2\right)}$$

The plot of these functions look as below.

[image]

Comment: But are $f$ and $g$ satisfying the condition for "complete monotonicity":  
 The $n$'th derivatives of each function satisfies $(−1)^ n f^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$, $(−1)^ n g^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$, $x \in (0, \infty)$?